# SDDM wont use my Theme in Lock Screen, am i make it wrong?

Tags: archlinux, kde-plasma

Im Using KDE for my desktop, i want to change my login screen, i've installing the themes from **system settings** and applied the changes. the theme is working on **boot login**, but somehow if i manage to **lock screen** it wont make a changes. im using login theme called "Sweet" .
here's code from `/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf`

```
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
Session=
User=

[General]
HaltCommand=/usr/bin/systemctl poweroff
RebootCommand=/usr/bin/systemctl reboot

[Theme]
Current=Sweet

[Users]
MaximumUid=60000
MinimumUid=1000

[X11]
ServerArguments=-dpi 0
```

i've tried to edit my `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/default.conf` to same as `/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf` then rebooted as well but same like before, it wont work on **lock screen**

btw, here's the output from `sddm --test-mode`

```
[kuntulsu@Harissen ~] $ sddm --test-mode
[23:24:16.675] (II) DAEMON: Initializing...
[23:24:16.713] (II) DAEMON: Starting...
[23:24:16.714] (II) DAEMON: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
[23:24:16.715] (II) DAEMON: Loading theme configuration from ""
[23:24:16.715] (II) DAEMON: Display server starting...
[23:24:16.719] (EE) DAEMON: Failed to start display server process.
[23:24:16.719] (EE) DAEMON: Display server failed to start. Exiting
Aborted (core dumped)
```

i have noticed that line 4, the themes is not defined but i have no idea to do to fix that, please help me

Answer (score 2):

In KDE **Login Screen** is not the same as **Lock Screen**. You installed and changed your **Login Screen (SDDM theme)**. The lockscreen is part of KDE theming, nothing to do with sddm.

You can find your lockscreen config at `~/.config/kscreenlockerrc`